# Bought a new headset but no one can hear me

Tags: xbox-360

About a week ago I bought a BigBen XHS10 headset for the XBOX 360. I installed the headset completely and bought the audio cable.

I do hear sound but no one can hear my and it seems like my microphone is not working.
How can i fix this is?

I cant find a solution on the internet about this can please somone help me!

Comment: does the microphone work on your computer?

Comment: I'm struggling a little bit to see how this might be somewhat related to gaming.

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms Well, it *is* a headset for a gaming console. That does, I think, make it gaming-specific hardware.

Comment: @RainierIaan -- Have you checked the microphone mute switch on the cable?

Comment: There's a cable that goes between the headset and the controller.  Have you checked that it is properly plugged in on both ends?  Also, sometimes I have to unplug and replug my controller if I'm not getting audio.  If you join a party (even by yourself) and then look at the party screen, it will show if the mic is registering you or not.  I find that helpful for debug.

Comment: @TZXH I guess so, but it still seems more to be asking about system support than  gaming itself.

Comment: I agree with DEC. This question is about hardware, no matter what the ware is used for.

Comment: Did you have a working mic previously?

Answer (score 2):

I've had my fair share of microphone issues, so I can suggest a series of debug steps.

### Step 1

Check to see if your XBox can hear you.  As **agent86** mentioned, there is a small icon that will blink "on" if you are in a party and talking.  The icon also looks different if you don't have a microphone connected, so that can be a clue.  You can also "Record a Voice Message" to send to friend, and then hit the playback button before sending it.  If you hear dead air, the XBox isn't getting anything from you.

### Step 2

Check the headphone to controller connection.  Both ends of these cables are prone to coming loose, and I find that the headphone side sometimes needs a lot of force to fully engage.  Look at the connectors when they are installed to see if they are fully seated correctly.  As **TZHX** mentioned, you should also check for an inline mute button, which many headphones feature on this cable, or sometimes on the connector to the XBox controller.

### Step 3

Verify your 360 controller mic input is not busted.  You may try connecting your headphones to a different controller, and/or connecting a different set of headphones to the controller you are using.  If you don't have a spare set of headphones you might ask around.  Often times folks have the cheapo "starter" headphones lying around.

If all of these steps fail, it's most likely that you just got a bad set of headphones.  If you have the right adapter cables, you can try connecting to your PC as **RayofCommand** suggested, but if this works you may still be stuck in a situation where the mic doesn't work where you want it to - on the 360.